# Add gradient background and image on the same element on ie8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, background-image

I'm trying to add a image to a span that has gradient background.
All good on the other browsers but on **IE8** the image is not displayed correctly.

```
background: url("../img/Checked.png") no-repeat 160px 0px, -ms-linear-gradient(top, #63b6db 0%,#309dcf 100%);

 background: url("../img/Checked.png") no-repeat 160px 0px, linear-gradient(to bottom, #63b6db 0%,#309dcf 100%);

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#63b6db',    endColorstr='#309dcf',GradientType=0 ),progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
(src="../img/Checked.png", sizingMethod="scale");
```

color: #fff;

So how can I do this on **IE8** to be displayed correct?
ty.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GpdgF/702/)**

Comment: it is likely that your background image declaration is clashing with the ms gradient filters. you can try to separate the declarations individually so that background-image handles the image and background-colour handles the colour / gradient.

alternatively, why don't you add an <img src=""/> directly to the <span> and then apply the gradient filter to the it instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use modernizr.js

go through the doc and download http://modernizr.com/

it will solve your most of the IE 8 css problems
```